# Power Bi - How to group by columns and get count of blank values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am fairly new to PowerBI/DAX. I am trying to figure out how I can dynamically calculate the # of blank values I have in every desired column.

For example,

```
Column Header | Count Blank Rows
City | 5
State | 2
Zip | 3
```

I am hoping to avoid making many measures of COUNTBLANK("columnName") as I have many columns to run against. Looking for a way to do this in one measure that will calculate the blanks based on the columns selected in my visual.

[Example of Table I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTCZr.png)

Comment: what are those 5,2,and 3 ?

Comment: examples of how many blank rows are found in that column. So the city column had 5 blank rows. The State column had 2 blank rows.

Answer (score 1):

To count blank values use:

```
COUNTBLANK(MyTable[MyColumn])
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment about managing this for all columns in a table, I don't know of a way to do this dynamically, but you can use Tabular Editor to generate the measures.  I highly recommend this tool to aid with any PBIX development.

Here is what it looks like to generate measures:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AEGwImgERl9hipdQ

The steps are:

1. open tabular editor from the external tools tab in powerbi
2. Paste this script into the c# tab (sorry for the formatting issue):

> foreach(var column in Selected.Columns) {
> var daxMeasure = String.Format("COUNTBLANK('{0}'{1}) / COUNTROWS('{0}')"
> , column.Table.Name
> , column.DaxObjectName);
> var newMeasure = column.Table.AddMeasure(
> column.Name + "_BlankPct",
> daxMeasure,
> column.DisplayFolder
> );
> newMeasure.FormatString = "0.0%"; }

3. Select the columns you want to create the measure for
4. Hit the play button on the script
5. Save the changes back to the pbix file

Back in PowerBI, you can select the measures into a table and show them on columns or rows:
[image]

The free version of Tabular Editor can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/TabularEditor/TabularEditor/releases/tag/2.17.2

Comment: I have many columns to assess. I was hoping for a more universal measure that would calculate the # of blanks values per whichever column I have selected in my visualization. Does this make sense?

Comment: Updated my answer for something that will achieve the goal for all columns

Answer (score 0):

Please check my solution, and let me know If It is something useful for you! It is close to the solution you are looking for , but not exact!

[image: TTLB]

You can use this DAX Code using SUMMARIZE by grouping multiple columns, and Result shows if there is at least one blank cell in the grouped array. Please see the code:

```
CountBlankRowValues = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(Geography,Geography[State],Geography[City],Geography[Zip]),
        Geography[State] = BLANK() || Geography[City] = BLANK() || Geography[Zip] = BLANK()
    )
)
```

And You can put it on a card visual to see the result:

[image: 7Rows]

Comment: Thanks Ozan! Your first method is an option and I have begun something similar using COUNTBLANK() - however, i have over 50 columns so I was hoping to avoid creating a measure for each one. My data model is already huge. The second/alternative solution isn't an option because it would then filter apply filters to other columns and I want to look at blanks across the entire dataset (by column)

Comment: I understand, @KenKelemen; but you need to understand that There is no cell concept in Power BI , like in Excel. It works on Column logic! I have no idea how to bring together all those blank values.

Comment: @KenKelemen Please check my updated solution and let me know If It is useful for you!